# Laravel 5 Route error not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I`m new to the laravel 5.4.what i want to do is when i press the See Here green color button,All the details need to be shown in new view called seedetails.blade.php according to relevant Trainee_ID.for an example if i press MOB/TR 1741 See details button all the data in the database need to shown only according to that ID. see the interface .

[image]

relevant view for that view.

```
 <table class="table table-striped">
                  <thead>
                    <th>Trainee ID</th>
                    <th>Name with Initials</th>
                    <th>Working Division</th>
                    <th>Starting Date</th>
                    <th>Ending Date</th>
                    <th>See All the Details<</th>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    @foreach($items as $item)
                     <tr>
                  <td>{{ $item->trainee_id }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $item->name_with_initials }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $item->trainee_division }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $item->start_date }}</td>
                  <td>{{ $item->end_date }}</td>
                   <td>
                   <a  class="btn btn-success" href="Seedetails/{{ $item->traninee_id }}">See Here</a>
                 </td>
              </tr>
                    @endforeach
                  </tbody>
          </table>
```

Here is the necessary controller for retrive data according to trainee_id

```
public function user_details($traninee_id)
{
    $trainee_details= registerdetails::where('id','=',$traninee_id)->get()->first();
     return view('registeredusers.seedetails', compact('trainee_details'));
}
```

Here is the seedetails.blade.php which should retrieve the data and shown.which is linked to above view`s see button ,see the code.

```
`<div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
             <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
             <table class="table table-bordered">

              <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Full Name</td>
                    <td>{{ $item->full_name }}</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td>Nic No</td>
                    <td>{{ $item->nic_no }}</td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                    <td>Date Of Birth</td>
                    <td>{{ $item->date_of_birth }}</td>
                  </tr>
              </tbody>
             </table> 
             </div>
             </div>
             </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Route for that view

```
Route::get('Seedetails/{id}', 'UserRegisterController@user_details');
```

Then this is the error now um getting when i press the See details button.

[image]

Comment: @Zayn Ali. please check out this sir,

Comment: have you tried Route::get('/Seedetails/{id?}', 'UserRegisterController@user_details');

Comment: Can you please post the URL that it's failing on?

Comment: @Aaron Fahey this is the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/Seedetails/

Comment: The ID is not showing there, hence the 404. Your route is expecting an `id`, can you make sure that the ID is being passed through correctly. Should be something like 127.0.0.1:8000/Seedetails/123

Comment: Are you misspelling `traninee_id`?

Comment: @sisve sir at where?

Comment: @Dasun `href="Seedetails/{{ $item->traninee_id }}"`

Comment: @AaronFahey Now URL like this http://127.0.0.1:8000/Seedetails/MOB%2FTR%2F1743.now it is ok i hope.but the error as same as previous

Comment: <a  class="btn btn-success" href="{{ url('Seedetails/').urlencode($item->traninee_id)}}">See Here</a> @Dasun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are making a big mistake, try to pass the name of the column you have in the database to the route, so that you dont make a mistake, anyways try this in the html

```
<td>
<a class="btn btn-success" href="Seedetails/{{ $item->trainee_id }}">See Here</a>
</td>
```

and if possible rename your route to

```
Route::get('Seedetails/{trainee_id?}', 'UserRegisterController@user_details')->where('trainee_id', '(.*)');;
```

Comment: Sir, i change the code you given,but the error as the same i mentioned in the question

Comment: can you post one thing? just check the link that you can see in the see more button. right click to inspect the href and post it here

Comment: @Exprator.I try out your edited code sample.it works fine on URL,but the view error says Undefined variable item,can you please come into my chat box so that i can show it to u as a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use URL Helper

```
  <a  class="btn btn-success" href="{{ URL::to('Seedetails/'.$item->traninee_id) }}">See Here</a>
```

OR alternatively

```
<a  class="btn btn-success" href="{{ url('Seedetails/'.$item->traninee_id) }}">See Here</a>
```

for more helpers refer to https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#urls

Comment: Sir, i change it, so that it give Internal error: Failed to retrieve the default value

Comment: Internal error: Failed to retrieve the default value

Comment: The error is in your $item->trainee_id  which is consist of backslashes you need to find another way to load data rather than using that format ID

Comment: Either try to str_slug() from blade and convert back into the Controller function user_details() to fetch data from the database.

Comment: Sir Now URL is Ok i guss http://127.0.0.1:8000/Seedetails/MOB%2FTR%2F1743. so that again it gives error as same as i mentioned in the question.why is that?

Comment: Because laravel router will consider MOB as the passed ID but when you are passing additional parameters in URL, Laravel looks for the same route which it cannot find  and throw this error

Comment: you can, ,  is that's the ID stored in Database ?? i mean with backslashes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147020/discussion-between-dasun-and-saad-bhutto).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using regular expression. Because in trainee id contained slash :
 May be You have mistaken the correct spelling of trainee id in url.

```
 <a  class="btn btn-success" href="{{url('/',[$item->trainee_id])}}">See Here</a>
```

use this route

```
Route::any('{id}','UserRegisterController@user_details')->where('id', '(.*)');
```

Comment: i try out this as well sir,but it gives error called Internal error: Failed to retrieve the default value

Comment: if your trainee_id field is mandatory then it does not throw error else do